# no puedo conectarme a sql server con node.js mediante mssql

Tags: sql-server, nodejs

me da el siguiente error:

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.
> at C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:71:17
> at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1027:9)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:482:26)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:375:28)
> at Connection.emit (domain.js:470:12)
> at Connection.emit (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1055:18)
> at Parser. (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2668:20)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)
> at Parser.emit (events.js:375:28)
> at Parser.emit (domain.js:470:12) {   code: 'ELOGIN',   originalError: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.
> at ConnectionError (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
> at Parser. (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1178:51)
> at Parser.emit (events.js:375:28)
> at Parser.emit (domain.js:470:12)
> at Readable. (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
> at Readable.emit (events.js:375:28)
> at Readable.emit (domain.js:470:12)
> at addChunk (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:298:12)
> at readableAddChunk (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:280:11)
> at Readable.push (C:\Users\onli\Desktop\rest_mssql\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:241:10)
> {
> code: 'ELOGIN'   }

Mi archivo de configuración

```
import sql from "mssql";
    
    const dbConfig = {
      server: "localhost",
      user: "sa",
      password: "EDWINESPINAL",
      database: "prueba",
      options: {
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
      },
    };
    
    async function getConnection() {
      try {
        const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
        conn
          .connect()
          .then(() => {
            const req = new sql.Request(conn);
            req.query("select * from cliente").then((client) => {
              console.log(client);
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    getConnection();
```

Este es el código que tengo, he estado varias horas y no doy con el problema.

he visto varias formas en youtube y tampoco me han resultado

Comment: No uso mucho sql server, pero por el stacktrace puedo suponer que el error tiene que ver con la autenticación del usuario `sa` (¿no `sa` es el "root" de sql server? ¿por qué conectarte con ese usuario?). Checa la contraseña o los métodos de autenticación.

Comment: Si te conectas por algun IDE o mediante CLI te funciona la conexión?

Comment: cree otro usuario y también me da ese error y si me puedo conectar por smss